# Adding custom UIView to UIViewController in - (void)loadView (Objective-C)

Tags: uiviewcontroller, subview, loadview

I am taking a programming class (for noobs) and I need to create the `UIViewController` `graphViewController`'s view programmatically (without interface builder).

The view is simple, it only consists of an `IBOUtlet` which is an instance of a `UIView` subclass called `GraphView`. `graphView` responds to several multitouch gestures for zooming and panning and what-not, but I handle all of that stuff in `- (void)viewDidLoad`.

I am doing just the creation of the `self.view` property and `graphView` in the code below:

```
- (void)loadView
{
    UIView *gvcView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
    self.view = gvcView;
    [gvcView release];

    GraphView *aGraph = [[GraphView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    self.graphView = aGraph;
    [aGraph release];

}
```

When I run the app I do not see the `graphView` view in there. I just get a transparent view which shows the "My Universal App" label. I'm stumped. Please help.

Let me know if you need additional code.

Thanks!

Update: Big thanks to BJ Homer for the quick fix!

had to do the following:

add this line of code: `[self.view addSubview:self.graphView];` at the end.

I was also getting this strange bug where `graphView` was showing up as completely black. This line of code fixed that: `self.graphView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];`

And that's it!

Final question: Is the default background color black for a custom UIView?

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[self.view addSubview:self.graphView];
```

Until you add your graph view to a parent view, UIKit doesn't know where to display it. `self.view` is special, since that's the property that `-loadView` is supposed to set. That view will automatically be added to the screen. But your graph view is just floating off in the ether until you add it somewhere.

Comment: That did the trick! I had tried that before and got a black screen in place of a cartesian coordinate system (which is what the view does). Do you think this is because I need to set the stretchyness of the `graphView` in code as well? This view goes into a `UINavigationController`